# Issue within certification chain using azure application gateway

Tags: azure, docker, certificate, azure-application-gateway

I'm using an Azure Application Gateway v2 to route traffic to a backendpool containing VMs running some docker container hosting an aspnet core webapi. The application is listeing in port 443. 
The gateway listener is configured to accept HTTPS connections. A pfx certificate has also been added. 
The HTTP setting of the gateway is configured as follow:
[image]

I've provided, hopefully, the correct root certificate for the setting. I've exported the certifacte as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/application-gateway/certificates-for-backend-authentication

[image]

All VMs from the backend pool use the same certificate as the gateway listener.
[image]

When calling the api using a C# application or open a specific url within a browser, the connections seems to be trusted.

[image]

But I get an error when calling the api using postman with endabled SSL cerificate verification. 
**Error: unable to verify the first certificate**

A check on sslhopper.com also indicates an issue within the chain. 
[image]

I got further information doing a chekc on digicert.com.

*TLS Certificate is not trusted
The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store). If you bought the certificate from a trusted authority, you probably just need to install one or more Intermediate certificates. Contact your certificate provider for assistance doing this for your server platform.*

I'm really stuck in resolving the issue. All helpful hints are very welcome. 
The production environment, running on a Windows Server, wihtout the Gateway but the same certificates is valid. So the issue must be somewhere in the gateway configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The crucial clue was delivered from a blog post. 
http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2019/08/azure-application-gateway-certificate-gotchas/
Gateway V2: the importance of the certificate chain

I did a new export of the pfx certificate including the whole chain and uploaded it to the gateway.

Comment: How did you export to pfx?
I have generated from godaddy, got my private key , private key pem and crt, 
i used this command to export to pfx, openssl pkcs12 -inkey bob_key.pem -in bob_cert.cert -export -out bob_pfx.pfx

still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If the cert is not trusted, then you need to check the Application Gateway Listener. Make sure that you are not using Basic listener.

If you are using multi-site listener, make sure that the host name which you have mentioned matches with the certificate CN

Comment: My information may have been misleading. It's always the same hostname and API running on the machines from the backend pool  Nevertheless I updated to a multisite listener and added the hostname there.  
It makes no difference whether the checkbox for a "Use Well Known CA Certificate" is set or not (with an added root certificate).

https://imgur.com/a/pPn5koT


On the right side is the check of the Azure instance. 
"The higher-level certificate is unfortunately not known. "

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of your HTTPS listener config?